# webpack-cli Running multiple commands at the same time is not possible

Tags: reactjs, django, webpack

I am trying to made a full stack project using react and django from the tuto of bad traversy of react and django here react it is a django app i flow the tuto and when it coming to excute the flowing command npm run dev and dev it is    `"dev":" webpack --mode development ./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./leadmanager/frontend/static/main.js",`
i have some errors  they are

```
    (venv) youssef@youssef-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~/Desktop/fullstack$ npm run dev

> fullstack@1.0.0 dev /home/youssef/Desktop/fullstack
>  webpack --mode development ./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./leadmanager/frontend/static/

[webpack-cli] Running multiple commands at the same time is not possible
```

[webpack-cli Found commands: 'bundle', './leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js'
webpack-cli Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! fullstack@1.0.0 dev:  `webpack --mode development ./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./leadmanager/frontend/static/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fullstack@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/youssef/.npm/_logs/2020-12-29T13_19_24_663Z-debug.log
```

Comment: webpack-cli :Running multiple commands at the same time is not possible

Comment: Same here, I am also getting the same error.

Answer (score 8):

From [docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/) try to use it as following:

`webpack --mode development --entry ./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./leadmanager/frontend/static/main.js`

Notice the `--entry`

And also you might want to change `--output-path` part to look like: `--output-path ./leadmanager/frontend/static/frontend/`

Answer (score 4):

Not certain if it's a bug or if there's an updated format to the scripts, but rolling back to webpack-cli verson 4.2.0 works.

npm i -D webpack-cli@4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

As PaulESPN mentioned, it looks like it’s a bug in the latest cli (4.3.0) The workaround it’s to explicitly list the command first, I.e. `webpack serve` where you replace `serve` with the command you’re trying to use.